# Real Time File Search

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to solve an activity in which I ask for a program that provides the file search feature in real time. As you type a directory name in the text box, the program should search and display in the text area the names of all files and sub-directories it finds in the directory, whose name is in the text box.

I managed to get it to list the directory folder `"C: /"` but the subfolders and files it does not list. If anyone can help me I appreciate it.

Follows the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

public class PesquisarArquivoGUI extends JFrame  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public PesquisarArquivoGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 410, 423);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblDiretrio = new JLabel("Diret\u00F3rio:");
        lblDiretrio.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        lblDiretrio.setBounds(10, 11, 64, 17);
        contentPane.add(lblDiretrio);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                File arquivo = new File("C:\\");

                File[] lista = arquivo.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                        return pathname.getName().contains(textField.getText());
                    }
                });

                for(File f : lista)
                    textArea.setText(f.getPath());
            }
        });


        textField.setBounds(73, 11, 311, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 43, 394, 341);

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing: `arquivo.listFiles(...)` only finds files _directly contained_ in the directory named by `arquivo`; `arquivo` always references `c:\ ` so you'll only see files at the top level of drive C:.  if you want to find files further down in the directory structure, you must recursively list out the files in each directory you encounter.  Second, instead of a `KeyListener`, you might find a `DocumentListener` more useful.

Comment: You list the files in the root directory, `C:`. If one of those files is a directory, you want to list all of its files and so on. In other words it is a recursive process. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but have you seen: [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) Also, to listen for changes in the contents of a `JTextField`, you usually implement a `DocumentListener`. Have you seen: [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051427/how-to-delete-files-from-the-directory-by-specifying-it-in-the-output-applicatio/58054315#58054315. The example add the files to a JTable so you will need to modify the code to add the files to a JTextArea.